# How can I tikz the equivalence (i.e. $\Leftrightarrow$) as arrow?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows

I found in the manual that `implies` is the right kind of arrow tip, so I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
  \draw[<->,double equal sign distance,implies] (2,1) -- (3,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But somehow, `implies` breaks `<->`, such that only one end of the line gets an arrow tip.

So how do I get the equivalence as arrow in Tikz?

---

I searched for another suitable arrow tip (like `equivalent`) or another suitable parameter instead of `<->` to say that both line ends should get the arrow tip, but did not find anything.

Comment: how to obtain an equivalence with a colorful side please ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`implies` is the name of a TikZ arrowhead (defined in the `arrows` TikZ library). It has to be combined with a hyphen (as in my code); it cannot be used as a PGF key on its own (as in your MWE). The following code produces the desired output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[implies-implies,double equal sign distance] (2,1) -- (3,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ohhhhh, so `implies` is just like `<` and `>` (and the direction is automatically correct). Thanks.

Comment: Before a confusion arises: `>=implies` and then `<->` works too. The comment with the hypen just means that `implies` is a arrow head just like `latex` or `to` or …

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel please how to obtain an equivalence with a colorful side?