# How can I tikz the equivalence (i.e. $\Leftrightarrow$) as arrow over a background color?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Follow-up question to [How can I tikz the equivalence (i.e. $\Leftrightarrow$) as arrow?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129916/how-can-i-tikz-the-equivalence-i-e-leftrightarrow-as-arrow)

What if I want to draw the equivalence arrow over a (non-white) background color? The fill option seems to have no effect.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{definition}[How to fill the following arrow with background color?]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[implies-implies,double equal sign distance,fill=bg] (2,1) -- (3,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{definition}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the `double` key, not `fill`. Also note that the `arrows.meta` library has superseded the `arrows` library.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{definition}[How to fill the following arrow with background color?]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[Implies-Implies,double equal sign distance,double=bg] (2,1) -- (3,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{definition}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to specify the double styling :

```
\draw[implies-implies,double equal sign distance,double=bg] (2,1) -- (3,2);
```