# New \Rightarrow with tikz

Tags: tikz-arrows

How can I draw `\Rightarrow` like this:?
[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\Arrow}[1]{%
\parbox{#1}{\tikz{\draw[->,line width=0.7pt,line cap=round](0,0)--(#1,0);}}
}
\newcommand{\myarrow}{\Arrow{.45cm}}

\begin{document}
4 \myarrow 2
\end{document}
```

**Update:**
How can i fix the left side?
[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\newcommand{\Arrow}[1]{%
\parbox{#1}{\tikz{\draw[-implies,double equal sign distance,line width=0.7pt,line cap=round](0,0)--(#1,0);}}
}
\newcommand{\myarrow}{\hspace{0.0cm}\Arrow{.45cm}\hspace{0.0cm}}

\begin{document}
4 \myarrow 2
\end{document}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question/problem? Your code produces exactly this picture. Is the question how to replace the arrow in `\Rightarrow` by your arrow? Or define a command that behaves like `\Rightarrow` in math mode?

Comment: @gernot I was able to draw new `rightarrow`. But I couldn't draw `Rightarrow`. I want to define a new `myRightarrow`. How can i draw using tikz?

Comment: I assume you mean you want a double line, you can add `,double` [but the output isn't great](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kWSp.png) so you'd need to fiddle with the parameters a bit

Comment: See [How can I tikz the equivalence (i.e. $\Leftrightarrow$) as arrow?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129916/82917)

Comment: Yes i want this @David Carlisle but the left side is a bit bad how do i fix it?

Comment: see campa's link

Comment: I looked but i need only right arrow @campa

Comment: yes but just don't use implies which is the double arrow surely there is enough there for you to get what you want. also why do you have the parbox here and why adding a space token after the box?

Comment: I think perhaps using the arrow `-{Classical TikZ Rightarrow}` (which needs `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}`) instead of the default `->` might be close to what you want. Also remove the `line cap`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for (compare use of `\Rightarrow` with that drawn with `TikZ`):

[image]

#### Notes:

- Earlier image had vertical artifcats. Turns out that this depends on the pdf bowser. Image here is produced usign Acrobat and no artifact is visible. Same file viewed in TeXShop or Preview on Mac shows the artifact.

#### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\newcommand{\myRightarrow}[1][0.32cm]{%
    \mathbin{
        \tikz [x=#1]
            \draw [
                draw=red,
                -{Classical TikZ Rightarrow[scale=0.45, line cap=round]}, 
                line width=0.40pt, 
                double=none,
                double distance=0.375ex,
            ] 
                (0,0) -- (1,0);
    }%
}%


\begin{document}
$4 \Rightarrow 2$

$4 \myRightarrow 2$
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the note: I think that your problem of the "artifcats" it is the same problem when you of tikz-cd. In fact I use xy package to delete this problem. (+1).

Comment: @Sebastiano how?

Comment: @cufcuf If you drawing a code using tikz-cd package you have a strange little vertical line.

Comment: @cufcuf: I suspect that the artifact bug will be resolved in a future update. One can always hack it and draw over those artifacts in white (or the background color) so that the artifacts dont show.

Comment: I tried to draw white on the background but I couldn't :) @Peter Grill

Comment: @cufcuf: Slightlly updated code. As the artifact is dependent on the pdf viewer, am going to ignore it for now. Hopefully future updates to the OS/pdf viewer will resolve that.